# z-scores of a series of percentages

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, standardization, z-score

Suppose I have a series of absolute values, for example the number of tourists in four different regions in a given year, let's say [100000, 200000, 50000, 1000000]. If I wanted to calculate the z-scores of the values ​​in the series I would have to subtract the mean from each value and then divide by the standard deviation.

But if I had a series of percentage values, for example the % of households with internet access in four different regions (the number of families in each region is obviously different), let's say [80%, 90%, 95%, 60%], would the procedure for calculating the z-scores be the same as in the previous case?

Comment: Why z scores?  That doesn't seem to make sense.  What's wrong with the original scale?

Comment: I have a dataframe where on the rows I have 20 regions, while on the columns I have phenomena (for example the % of families with internet access, the % of public services offered digitally, etc.). All values ​​in the dataframe are in %. I need to find an index (I was thinking of the z-score) to find a ranking for the regions.

Comment: Z score doesn't make sense for that purpose.

Comment: Could you please propose an alternative?

Comment: For rankings, would percentiles/quantile not be sufficient?

Comment: I wrote a new question, I hope it is more comprehensive. I'll delete this shortly.